# How Android-studio layout preview tool deal with '@+id' and '@id' exactly?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Surely I used `@id` after declared `@+id` and my App runs well with my code, what confused me is that when I preview my xml files, the reference `@id` seems not work at all and the layout was in my library project not main,which was dependenced by aar.

If I change the `layout_below="@id/tv_1` to `layout_below="@+id/tv_1`, the preview will work well.
Or I declare it in `id.xml` files id my library proj,and use `@id/tv_1`, preview works well too.

all solutions above seems make no difference after I run my main project,they all works well. I just can't understand why preview has problems,and how the '+' works when preview a xml file.

Examples:

```
<RelativeLayout ..>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_1" ../>

<EditText android:id="@+id/et_1"
android:layout_below="@id/tv_1" ../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Examples:

<RelativeLayout ..>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_1" ../>

<EditText android:id="@+id/et_1"
android:layout_below="@id/tv_1" ../>

</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 2):

`@+id` creates a new entry to R.java class which stores and identify assets.

`@id` simply refers to the previous created assest.